# Creating a VBScript object from a running process?

Tags: vbscript

I'm able to use VBScript to start an instance of Word, give it some commands, and terminate:

```
Dim WordApp
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
WordApp.DoSomething
WordApp.DoSomethingElse
WordApp.Quit
```

But if I have a running instance of word, can I connect to it using VBScript without starting up a new process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GetObject()` instead of `CreateObject()`. Pass the ProgId (`"Word.Application"`) as the 2nd parameter.

```
Dim WordApp
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

Comment: Note that this will always get the first running instance. Other instances are not accessible until that instance is terminated.